# Upgrade server running RHEL 7 with MySQL 5.7 to RHEL 8

Tags: mysql, rhel

We are looking at upgrading a backend server that runs RHEL 7 that hosts a MySQL 5.7 DB to RHEL 8.  I read that the RHEL AppStream only supports MySQL 8 and that we would need to make some updates to disable AppStream for MySQL and manually install MySQL 5.7.  Has anyone done this and what are your thoughts on the risk of using MySQL 5.7 on RHEL 8.  On the other hand, is it just a better idea to move to MySQL 8 and deal with the data migration before upgrading the OS?

Comment: This looks like a question for [SF] or [DBA.se]